# Laravel 5 raw select query doesn't return anything

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, mariadb

I am trying to retrieve data from a database and i need to run the sql as a raw query, this is how I do it:

```
$var = Nuti::select(DB::raw("select name, image, info from nuti
  where name like '%:search_term%'"), array("search_term" => $term));

return $var;
```

$var returns an empty array but when I try to run the same query directly in a mysql console, it returns two records.

[EDIT]

I just shortened the query when i posted this question, the need for a raw query is to do something more like this:

```
$var = Nuti::select(DB::raw("select name, image, info from nuti
  where name like '%:search_term%'") or info %like% '%:search_term%', array("search_term" => $term));

return $var;
```

Comment: Why do you need a raw query here?

Comment: `%` around `like`???

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in the following ways.

```
$data = Nuti::select(['name', 'image', 'info'])->where('name', 'like', "%{$term}%")->get();

$data = Nuti::selectRaw('name, image, info')->where('name', 'like', "%{$term}%")->get();

$data = DB::table('users')->select(['name', 'image', 'info'])->where('name', 'like', "%{$term}%")->get();

$data = DB::table('users')->selectRaw('name, image, info')->where('name', 'like', "%{$term}%")->get();

$data = DB::select("select name, image, info from nuti where name like '%{$term}%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You might just need to add ->get();

```
$var = Nuti::select(DB::raw("select name, image, info from nuti
      where name like '%:search_term%'"), array("search_term" => $term))->get();
```

You can debug with:

```
$var = Nuti::select(DB::raw("select name, image, info from nuti
  where name like '%:search_term%'"), array("search_term" => $term))->toSql(); 
dd($var);
```

**edit: What about this?**

```
$var = Nuti::select(DB::raw("select name, image, info from nuti
      where name like '%:".$term."%'"))->get();
```

Comment: I tried the debug version, but it gives me this: ErrorException in Grammar.php line 58: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is too complex for the query builder and you want to get an collection of models from a raw query, you can use `hydrateRaw()`:

```
$var = Nuti::hydrateRaw(
    "select name, image, info from nuti where name like :search_term",
    array("search_term" => "%{$term}%")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = Nuti::select(['name', 'image', 'info'])->where('name', 'like', "%{$term}%")->get();
return $var;
```

I think this is all you need.